# What's the input json file size limit in jq?

Tags: input, max, size, jq

Is there the maximum json file size that jq handles. I build jq 1.6 from github source.

I have tried to handle 288MB json file (in the following command, handwriting_data_info1.json) and got following errors:

```
$ jq 'INDEX(.images[]; .id) as $imgs | { "filename_with_label" :
                [ .annotations[] |
                 select(.attributes.type=="letter" ) |
                 $imgs[.image_id] + {label:.text} |
                {id:.id} + {filename:.file_name} + {label:.label}
                ]
                }' handwriting_data_info1.json > handwriting_data_info1_with_label.json

jq: src/jv.c:1261: jvp_object_get_slot: Assertion `slot == -1 || (slot >= 0 && slot < jvp_object_size(object))' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

FYI, jq filter defintion used above works well for relatively small size json files.

I think that there would be maximum input json file size for jq. If that's the case, is there way to increase input json file size for jq?

Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. jq can handle arbitrarily long streams of JSON, but if any single JSON item in the stream is too big to fit into memory, the "streaming parser" would have to be used.  This parser is only active if the `--stream` command-line option is specified.
2. The "streaming parser" is economical with memory but can be noticeably slow and somewhat difficult to use.  Further information about the streaming parser can be found in the jq manual and the [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ).
3. One way to verify whether jq can manage the input without using the --stream option is to run the `empty` filter, e.g.:

   jq empty INPUT.json
4. The posted error is an assertion error; such errors are normally unrelated to the size of the input entity or entities. Such errors, however, might be generated if the jq program attempts to generate large structures that don't fit into memory.

Apart from the above limitations imposed by RAM, I don't know of any other limits imposed on the size of JSON inputs, and I have seen jq process single JSON entities of several gigabytes each.

Comment: ```@peak``` Thanks for your anser again.
```jq empty handwriting_data_info1.json``` works without any warning or errors.
When I run the jq filter as posted, admin of system was doing system upgrade with ```sudo apt upgrade```. After upgrade, same jq command posted does not produce the error message.  It might update some library related to jq command.

It is very useful to use ```jq empty INPUT.json``` command to check if the jq can handle teh input file.